# Access Default Value - Next Full Hour

Tags: ms-access, time, vba, ms-access-2010, default-value

I've searched for hours and thought it would be simple but still have no idea.

I'm using access 2010 and have a form to enter the start time of a task. The startTime field is text so that I can use a drop down to select full hours e.g. 11:00; 12:00; 13:00.

How can I set the default value to the next full hour?

If the time is now 12:32 then the default value should be 13:00; if the time is now 14:16 the default value should be 15:00

Edited:

Correct: =TimeSerial(Hour(time())-(Minute(time())>=1);0;0)

Comment: When the time is exactly 07:00, should the next hour be 08:00?

Comment: It's for task management and should work similar to the reminder notifications in outlook, so preferably it should then be the next full hour; 07:00 would then be 08:00

Comment: Thanks HansUp but how do I get the function in the default properties of the field, not too familiar with access

Comment: This works as the default value: =TimeSerial(Hour(Now())-(Minute(Now())>=1);0;0)

Comment: I was confused about the default value aspect of the question so hoped showing you `DatePart` and `TimeSerial` would point you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CDate()` to convert the *startTime* string to a Date/Time value.  Then use `DatePart()` to get the hour.  Give `TimeSerial()` the hour plus one, and zero for the minutes and seconds.  Finally use `Format()` to convert the resulting Date/Time value back to a string.

Here is an Immediate window session which tests the function included below.

```vb
? NextHour("12:32")
13:00
? NextHour("07:00")
08:00

Public Function NextHour(ByVal pStartTime As String) As String
    Dim dteStart As Date
    Dim dteNext As Date

    dteStart = CDate(pStartTime)
    dteNext = TimeSerial(DatePart("h", dteStart) + 1, 0, 0)
    NextHour = Format(dteNext, "hh:nn")
End Function
```